Problema con el método contains en Java
estoy haciendo un ejercicio en Java cuyo enunciado es el siguiente:
Queremos crear un mapa que relacione estudiantes (dni, nombre y edad), con su información de contacto (email, dirección
y localidad). En este caso, la clase Estudiante representará a cada estudiante y contendrá su información, y la clase
InformacionContacto representará la información de contacto asociada a cada estudiante.

Añade al menos dos estudiantes al mapa
Utiliza el método contains para comprobar si un determinado estudiante, según un dni dado, existe en el mapa
Muestra todos los estudiantes y pide que dado un dni, se actualice la información de contacto

Tengo problemas con la parte de usar el método "contains" ya que da igual cómo lo haga siempre me devuelve un valor falso. ¿Me podrían ayudar por favor?
Código de la clase Contacto:
package actividaddeclase6mapas;

 public class Contacto {

//atributo(s)
String email;
String direccion;
String localidad;

//constructor por parámetros
public Contacto(String email, String direccion, String localidad){
    this.email = email;
    this.direccion = direccion;
    this.localidad = localidad;
}

//getters y setters

public String getEmail() {
    return this.email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getDireccion() {
    return this.direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public String getLocalidad() {
    return this.localidad;
}

public void setLocalidad(String localidad) {
    this.localidad = localidad;
}

//el to string como se llame

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "\nContacto [email=" + email + ", direccion=" + direccion + ", localidad=" + localidad + "]";
}

}
Código de la clase Alumno:
package actividaddeclase6mapas;

 public class Alumno {

//atributo(s)
String dni;
String nombre;
int edad;


//constructor por parámetros
public Alumno(String dni, String nombre, int edad){
    this.dni = dni;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
}

//getters y setters

public String getDni() {
    return this.dni;
}

public void setDni(String dni) {
    this.dni = dni;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return this.nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getEdad() {
    return this.edad;
}

public void setEdad(int edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
}



//el to string como se llame

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "\nAlumno [dni=" + dni + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", edad=" + edad + "]";
}

}
Código de la clase Principal:
package actividaddeclase6mapas;
           import java.util.Scanner;
            import java.util.HashMap;
             import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
            import java.util.Map;
            import java.util.TreeMap; //importar todo lo necesario
            public class Principal {
       public static void main(String[] args) {

    //activar Scanner
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\n");
    
    //crear el mapa
    Map<Alumno, Contacto> alumnos = new HashMap<>();

    //crear los objetos de los alumnos
    Alumno alumno1 = new Alumno("12345678A", "Mirake Tecasko", 19);
    Alumno alumno2 = new Alumno("87654321B", "Mila Groso", 25);

    //crear los objetos de contacto
    Contacto contactoAlumno1 = new Contacto("sitiene@sitiene.com", "Calle de la no existencia 17", "Bezanzon");
    Contacto contactoAlumno2 = new Contacto("notengo@notengo.com", "Calle de la invención 69", "Londres");


    //añadir al menos 2 alumnos
    alumnos.put(alumno1, contactoAlumno1);
    alumnos.put(alumno2, contactoAlumno2);

    //mostrar los datos hasta ahora
    System.out.println(alumnos);

    //Utiliza el método contains para comprobar si un determinado estudiante, según un dni dado, existe en el mapa
    System.out.println(alumnos.containsKey("12345678A"));

    //Muestra todos los estudiantes y pide que dado un dni, se actualice la información de contacto
    System.out.print("Por favor, escribe el dni cuya información de contacto deseas actualizar: ");
    String dniContacto = sc.nextLine();

        //actualizar la información de contacto
        for (Map.Entry<Alumno, Contacto> entry : alumnos.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey().getDni().equals(dniContacto)) {
                System.out.print("Por favor, introduce el nuevo email: ");
                String nuevoEmail = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Por favor, introduce la nueva dirección: ");
                String nuevaDireccion = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Por favor, introduce la nueva ciudad: ");
                String nuevaCiudad = sc.nextLine();

                // actualizar el contacto
                Contacto contactoActualizado = new Contacto(nuevoEmail, nuevaDireccion, nuevaCiudad);
                alumnos.put(entry.getKey(), contactoActualizado);
                System.out.println("Información actualizada para el alumno con DNI '" + dniContacto);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(alumnos);

}

}
